# Is there a benefit to using as much <style> elements/attributes as possible in SVG?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

Below I have the same SVG file written in two styles: one with (almost) as much `<style>` elements/attributes as possible, and another with none. Is there any practical difference between the two other than character count and aesthetics?

My best guess would be that the answer if any is somehow related to backwards compatibility, performance, and/or the transition from *SMIL* to *CSS animations / Web Animations*, but those are just shots in the dark. I'm mainly concerned about the compatibility part, though.

**With `<style>` elements/attributes**:

```
<svg xmlns="http: //www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-50 -50 200 200">
  <style>
    path, .path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 2.25;
    }
  </style>
  <rect style="fill: none; x: -50; y: -50; width: 200; height: 200;"/>
  <rect class="path" style="fill: #fff; x: 1.125; y: 1.125; width: 97.75; height: 97.75;"/>
  <rect style="x: 34; y: 87.5; width: 2.5; height: 2.5;"/>
  <path d="M41,84 q3,1 9,1 t9,-1"/>
  <polygon points="45,80 50,71 55,80 50,78"/>
  <polygon points="67,77 62,73 62,76"/>
  <polygon points="33,77 38,73 38,76"/>
  <circle style="cx: 73.5; cy: 71; r: 5;"/>
  <circle style="cx: 26.5; cy: 71; r: 5;"/>
  <path d="M63.5,71 q3,-5 10.5,-5 t10.5,5"/>
  <path d="M15.5,71 q3,-5 10.5,-5 t10.5,5"/>
  <polygon points="86,64 76,58 64,60 63,64 77,62"/>
  <polygon points="14,64 24,58 36,60 37,64 23,62"/>
</svg>
```

**Without `<style>` elements/attributes**:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-50 -50 200 200">
  <rect fill="none" x="-50" y="-50" width="200" height="200"/>
  <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2.25" x="1.125" y="1.125" width="97.75" height="97.75"/>
  <rect x="34" y="87.5" width="2.5" height="2.5"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2.25" d="M41,84 q3,1 9,1 t9,-1"/>
  <polygon points="45,80 50,71 55,80 50,78"/>
  <polygon points="67,77 62,73 62,76"/>
  <polygon points="33,77 38,73 38,76"/>
  <circle cx="73.5" cy="71" r="5"/>
  <circle cx="26.5" cy="71" r="5"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2.25" d="M63.5,71 q3,-5 10.5,-5 t10.5,5"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2.25" d="M15.5,71 q3,-5 10.5,-5 t10.5,5"/>
  <polygon points="86,64 76,58 64,60 63,64 77,62"/>
  <polygon points="14,64 24,58 36,60 37,64 23,62"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I prefer to put everything in the CSS since this is reducing verbosity and It's easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have the same amount of CSS styling. Many [SVG attributes map to CSS properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#UsingPresentationAttributes). In the second example that's what you're doing. Apart from a slight difference in CSS specificity everything is the same.

Comment: Something interesting and related I found in [the spec for SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html): "In the future, any new properties that apply to SVG content will not gain presentation attributes. Therefore, authors are suggested to use styling properties, either through inline `‘style’` properties or style sheets, rather than presentation attributes, for styling SVG content."

Comment: Note: there is still limited support for [geometry properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/geometry.html#geometry-properties) in SVG. For elements with geometry properties, Firefox displays an `Invalid property name` warning, Illustrator converts these elements to `<polygon points="0,0 0,0 0,0 "/>`, and Inkscape doesn’t render these elements at all.

I’d avoid geometry properties and just stick with presentation attributes for position and dimensions, at least until support is stable. Doing so would also allow for consistency with elements that do not have geometry properties, like `’text’`.

Comment: Clarification: the `<rect>` and `<circle>` elements in my question's example (e.g., `<circle style="cx: 26.5; cy: 71; r: 5;"/>`) are converted to `<polygon points="0,0 0,0 0,0 "/>` when opened in Illustrator.

Comment: Well Firefox supports the geometry properties of SVG 2. It does not display Invalid property name although I admit such support is fairly recent.